# C++ Brute Force attack function does not return results

Tags: c++, for-loop, recursion, brute-force

so I'm currently working on a brute force attacker project in C++. I've managed to get it working, but one problem that I'm facing is that if the program actually managed to get a correct guess, the function still goes on. I think the problem is that the program fails to return a guess. Take a look at my code:
(Sorry for the mess, by the way, I'm not that experienced in C++ - I used to code in Python/JS.)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>

std::string chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
std::string iterateStr(std::string s, std::string guess, int pos);
std::string crack(std::string s);
std::string iterateChar(std::string s, std::string guess, int pos);

int main() {

    crack("bb");

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

// this function iterates through the letters of the alphabet
std::string iterateChar(std::string s, std::string guess, int pos) {
    for(int i = 0; i < chars.length(); i++) {
        // sets the char to a certain letter from the chars variable
        guess[pos] = chars[i];
        // if the position reaches the end of the string
        if(pos == s.length()) {
            if(guess.compare(s) == 0) {
                break;
            } 
        } else {
            // else, recursively call the function
            std::cout << guess << " : " << s << std::endl;
            iterateChar(s, guess, pos+1);
        }
    }
    return guess;
}

// this function iterates through the characters in the string
std::string iterateStr(std::string s, std::string guess, int pos) {
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        guess = iterateChar(s, guess, i);
        if(s.compare(guess) == 0) {
            return guess;
        }
    }
    return guess;
}

std::string crack(std::string s) {
    int len = s.length();
    std::string newS(len, 'a');
    std::string newGuess;
    newGuess = iterateStr(s, newS, 0);
    return newGuess;
}
```

Edit : Updated code.

Comment: Think about this:  How can you tell if `iterateChar` returns because it found what it was looking for, or because it ran out of guesses and failed?  Once you figure that out, then use that to determine if the recursive call needs to keep looping or stop.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm, hey, thanks for your answer - I've did some testing and fixed the code a bit - can you check my answer below?

Comment: I've tried your code and I used the word `abduct` since it doesn't take as long and when the output was at `abduct` it continued right past it! The code is not breaking when a match is found.

Answer (score 1):

The main flaw in the posted code is that the recursive function returns a string (the guessed password) without a clear indication for the caller that the password was found.

Passing around all the strings by value, is also a potential efficiency problem, but the OP should be worried by snippets like this:

```
guess[pos] = chars[i];  // 'chars' contains the alphabet

if(pos == s.length()) {
    if(guess.compare(s) == 0) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Where `guess` and `s` are strings of the same length. If that length is 2 (OP's last example), `guess[2]` is outside the bounds, but the successive call to `guess.compare(s)` will compare only the two chars "inside".

The loop inside `iterateStr` does nothing useful too, and the `pos` parameter is unused.

Rather than fixing this attempt, it may be better to rewrite it from scratch

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>

// Sets up the variable and start the brute force search
template <class Predicate>
auto crack(std::string const &src, size_t length, Predicate is_correct)
    -> std::pair<bool, std::string>;

// Implements the brute force search in a single recursive function. It uses a
// lambda to check the password, instead of passing it directly
template <class Predicate>
bool recursive_search(std::string const &src, std::string &guess, size_t pos,
                      Predicate is_correct);

// Helper function, for testing purpouse
void test_cracker(std::string const &alphabet, std::string const &password);

int main()
{
    test_cracker("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", "dance");
    test_cracker("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ", "go on");
    test_cracker("0123456789", "42");
    test_cracker("0123456789", "one");     // <- 'Password not found.'
}

void test_cracker(std::string const &alphabet, std::string const &password)
{
    auto [found, pwd] = crack(alphabet, password.length(),
        [&password] (std::string const &guess) { return guess == password; });

    std::cout << (found ? pwd : "Password not found.") << '\n';
}

// Brute force recursive search 
template <class Predicate>
bool recursive_search(std::string const &src, std::string &guess, size_t pos,
                      Predicate is_correct)
{
    if ( pos + 1 == guess.size() )
    {
        for (auto const ch : src)
        {
            guess[pos] = ch;

            if ( is_correct(guess) )
                return true;
        }     
    }
    else
    {
        for (auto const ch : src)
        {
            guess[pos] = ch;

            if ( recursive_search(src, guess, pos + 1, is_correct) )
                return true;
        }              
    }
    return false;
}

template <class Predicate>
auto crack(std::string const &src, size_t length, Predicate is_correct)
    -> std::pair<bool, std::string>
{
    if ( src.empty() )
        return { length == 0 && is_correct(src), src };

    std::string guess(length, src[0]);

    return { recursive_search(src, guess, 0, is_correct), guess };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried your code even with the modified version of your `iterateStr()` function. I used the word `abduct` as it is quicker to search for. When stepping through the debugger I noticed that your `iterateChar()` function was not returning when a match was found. Also I noticed that the length of `string s` being passed in was `6` however the guess string that is being updated on each iteration had a length of `7`. You might want to step through your code and check this out.

For example at on specific iteration the `s` string contains: `abduct` but the `guess` string contains `aaaabjz` then on the next iteration the `guess` string contains `aaaabkz`. This might be your concerning issue of why the loop or function continues even when you think a match is found.

The difference in lengths here could be your culprit.

Also when stepping through your modified code:

```
for ( size_t i = 0; i < s.length(); i++ ) {
    guess = iterCh( s, guess, i );
    std::cout << "in the iterStr loop\n";
    if ( guess.compare( s ) == 0 ) {
        return guess;
    }
}
return guess;
```

in your `iterateStr()` function the recursion always calls `guess = iterCh( s, guess, i );` and the code never prints `in the iterStr loop\n";`. Your `iterateChar` function is completing through the entire string or sequence of characters never finding and return a match. I even tried the word `abs` as it is easier and quicker to step through the debugger and I'm getting the same kind of results.

Comment: I tried my code, and I didn't find the problem of the guess string being longer than string s. The problem, it seems, that the iterateChar function is running through the entire string, even though I have a return statement. The return statement should work since I always manage to print "Aha!", but it doesn't work.